# PrintWriter and FileOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream, printwriter

`PrintWriter` is used to write data as text into files while `FileOutputStream` is used to write in binary.

Consider

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("data"));
        for(int i=1;i<=10;++i)
            pw.print(i);
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
12345678910
```

However, if I use `FileOutputStream` I get binary data which is not readable in text.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("data")) ; 
        for(int i= 1; i<=10; ++i)
            fos.write(i);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

gives output:

[image]

Now, if I use `PrintWriter` with `FileOutputStream`, then I still get text data as shown below. Why? How does it become text and why?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new FileOutputStream(new File("data")));
        for(int i=1 ;i<=10;++i)
            pw.print(i);

        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Output :

```
12345678910
```

****** Edit :***

Now consider , The case

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("data"))));
        for(int i=1 ;i<=10;++i)
            pw.print(i);

        pw.close();


    }


}
```

The output is still : 
    12345678910

According to JavaDocs :

> A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data
>   types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then
>   use a data input stream to read the data back in.

So, Now If PrintWriter is sending bytes to DataOutputStream , how does the whole thing works ?

Comment: DataOutputStream is redundant in your example. It doesn't do anything useful which is why it works, but it is confusing and you shouldn't use it if you are writing text.

Comment: What makes DataOutputStream redundant ? I am not able to get it.

Comment: If you take out DataOutputStream it will do exactly the same thing (very slightly faster). Thus it is redundant.

Comment: But DataOutputStream takes primitives , convert them to binary and then send it to FileOutputStream.  Here , DataOutputStream is getting Encoded Bytes. So , how does this explain ?

Comment: PrintWriter calls `dataOutputStream.write()`, which simply writes the byte to the underlying FileOutputStream. Look at the javadoc and the source code.

Comment: While DataOutputStream has those methods, you can't use any of them which is the confusing bit.  PrintWriter doesn't use them which is why it works, but if you attempt to use them you will end up with a confusing mix of text and binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files contain bytes. Always.

Characters are written into files by transforming characters into bytes, using an encoding. Many such encodings exist. For example, ASCII allows transforming 128 different characters to bytes. UTF-8 allows encoding any Unicode character to bytes. The two encodings, for example, transform the character '1' into the byte 49. '2' would be transformed into the byte 50.

When using a PrintWriter with a file name as argument, the PrintWriter actually opens a FileOuptutStream to write bytes to the file. When you write characters to the PrintWriter, the PrintWriter transforms characters to bytes using an encoding, and then write those bytes to the FileOutputStream, which writes the bytes to the file.

So, for example, if you use the following program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("data")) ; 
        for(int i = 49; i <= 58; ++i)
            fos.write(i);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

and then open the file with a text editor, you should see `123456789` in the file, because the code writes the byte representation (in ASCII or UTF8) of those characters directly.

Comment: please consider my updated question too ... Where I now have chained it with DataOutputstream

Comment: As Peter Lawrey says in his comment, the DataOutputStream is useless. It receives bytes and writes them, as is, to the FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the docs.

From [`FileOutputStream.html#write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write(int)):

> Writes the specified byte to this file output stream.

From [`PrintWriter.html#print(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print(int)):

> Prints an integer. The string produced by `String.valueOf(int)` is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

That is, this method will write numbers as you see them.
The other one writes bytes.
The byte value 9 is not the number 9, but an unreadable character.